# Rails - Can I use Ransack and CanCan together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan, ransack

I am trying to get search result depending upon the authorization of the user...

Answer (score 7):

After performing the Ransack search, just filter the result with CanCan. Here's an example where my app lists Providers.

If your abilities don't use blocks, use `accessible_by`:

```
def index
  @search = Provider.sorted.search(params[:q])
  @providers = @search.result.accessible_by(current_ability)
end
```

If your abilities are using blocks, you can't use `accessible_by`:

```
def index
  @search = Provider.sorted.search(params[:q])
  @providers = @search.result.select{|p| can? :read, p}
end
```

For more details and examples, check out the cancan wiki on [Fetching Records](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records)

Hope that helps

Comment: Did you test this? As I look into the cancan(can) code, it looks like accessible_by can not be used down the line in a chain of scopes...

Comment: Yes, `sorted` is a named scope on `Provider`. Check out [Fetching Records](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records) on the cancan wiki, which explains how `accessible_by` is a scope, so it can be chained with other scopes.

Answer (score 1):

```
As of 1.4 the index action will load the collection resource using accessible_by
```

So now we have all accessible records in `index` action. And hence following would work

```
def ProvidersController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @q = @providers.search(params[:q]).page(params[:page])
    @providers = @q.result
  end

end
```

Comment: For future people searching, this does not work by default and CanCan will not filter a ransack query.  you need to use the accepted answer.

Comment: It works for me, with the change that `search` is now `ransack`.  CanCanCan can filter an ActiveRecord relation, which is what `@providers` holds at the entry to `index`, if `load_and_authorize_resource` is included at the top of the controller.

Comment: It is still relevant. I am using Rails 6, Ruby 2.7, ransack (2.3.2), cancancan (3.0.2).  You many get `search` method deprecation warning but it works. I suggest start using `ransack` over `search`